# Java Swing grid of buttons with individual control

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I know how a grid of buttons are made, but what happens from the implementation is that once the button is added into the frame/panel, you can't refer to it as a JButton object. My question is once I create a grid full of buttons and add them into the panel, how would I change the button background or border when they are clicked?

```
public GridTest(int rows, int cols) {
Container pane = getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
String[] labels = {"A", "B", "C"};
for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  JButton button = new JButton(labels[i]);
  pane.add(button);
    }
}
```

How would I set the background of button with the "A" label to red when it is clicked on?

`if ("A".equals(actionCommand)) {...}`

Comment: Add them to an array or `List` or `Map` depending on your requirements

Comment: *"How would I set the background of button with the "A" label to red when it is clicked on?"* - `((JButton)evt.getSource()).setBackground(Color.RED)`

Comment: Hi, what is `evt.getSource()` exactly? How does that refer to the button with the label "A" specifically?

Comment: `evt` is an the instance of `ActionEvent` passed to the `actionPerformed` method. See [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: Earlier I used `String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();` to find out which button is being clicked, but now I'm trying to figure out what will allow me to modify the button background based on its label after it is clicked. Is there an alternative solution that also incorporates this command?

Comment: `e.getSource()` will return an instance of the component which triggered the event, ie the `JButton` in your case

Comment: @btrballin `I'm trying to figure out what will allow me to modify the button background based on its label after it is clicked` - the label is not important. The label is not important. The event will give you direct access to the button that was clicked, so you just set the background of the button as was demonstrated in the second comment. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33817303/131872. You will need to add the two lines of code to the ActionListener to change the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the components in the pane and (if possible) cast them to JButton.

```
for (Component c : pane.getComponents()) {
    if (c instanceof JButton) {
        JButton b = (JButton) c;
        // Now you can do whatever you want with b.
        // For example: b.setBackground(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous, as you can't tell the difference between the buttons in your grid and other buttons which might be within the same container.  Given the fact that the `ActionEvent` provides access to the source of the event (ie the `JButton`) it seems like a lot of work for little gain

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to act on click events to modify the source button, then the best practice is also the simplest:
Use [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html):

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        AbstractButton btnSource = ((AbstractButton)e.getSource());
        // handle btnSource 
    }
});
```

If you intend to modify other components as well, you can always add them to an internal container (e.g: ArrayList) and group them up into a logical unit.
You could then react on that logical unit as you require.